# R: For loop to perform Tidal analysis with Harmonic Constituents

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply

**EDITED, I have made progress, but didn't think my original question was as well constructed as it could be.

I am new to R and computer programming in general and I am attempting to write my first for loop.

I want to be able to do some tidal analysis using harmonic constituents from NOAA.

I have my initial data=data which looks like:

```
Constituent #   Name    Amplitude      Phase      Speed        
1                M2      3.264         29.0       28.98 
2                S2      0.781         51.9       30.0  
3                N2      0.63          12.3       28.43 
4                K1      1.263        136.8       15.04 
5                M4      0.043        286.0       57.96
```

The equation for wave height is `h(t)= Amplitude*cos(Speed*t-Phase)` where t is time.

Therefore I need to perform this calculation for each constituent (row) and sum the results of each constituent by time.

So my middle result will be a table with the ncols=number of time stamps and the nrow= number of constituents.

```
                   T1                               T2                              T3...
data[1,3]*cos(data[1,4]*T1-data[1,3])    data[1,3]*cos(data[1,4]*T2-data[1,3])
data[2,3]*cos(data[2,4]*T1-data[2,3])    data[2,3]*cos(data[2,4]*T2-data[2,3])
                   .
                   .
                   .

data[n,3]*cos(data[n,4]*T1-data[n,3])    data[n,3]*cos(data[n,4]*T2-data[n,3])
```

With this table I can sum the columns to get my final answer of what the tide height is at each time stamp.

To do this I have attempted to create a for loop.

```
   DF=NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  DF<- matrix(c(DF, data[i,2]*cos(pi/180*(data[i,4]*Time[,]-data[i,3]))))

}
```

This returns all the results a single vector.  I can't figure out how to separate it into columns by the timestamp.  It just runs through all the timestamps for the furst constituent, then the second and so on.  So for my current station I have 37 constituents and 100 time stamps so my matrix DF is 1 column with 3700 rows.

I have tried setting the matrix DF with the appropriate number of columns and rows, but this returns a single result for all rows and columns.  I have also tried a nested if statement with time, and many other things that I can't remember.

***Used Rusan's approach and finished what I was doing with the script below.  Any other approaches are appreciated.

```
Time<-matrix(seq(1,100,1))   #my time series
n<-hh3(Time)                 #Function outlined by Rusan below
b<- matrix(c(rep(Time[1,1]:Time[nrow(Time),1], nrow(wave_table))))    #A repeating list to bind with n
height<-matrix(colSums(dcast(data.frame(cbind(b,n)),Constituent~V1,value.var="V1.1")[,-1])) #The sums of all the constituents at each time stamp, the final height of the wave at each time
```

This allows me to sum all the constituents at each time stamp.  Height=sum of all constituents at time t.  So for my example above `height(t1)=M2(t1)+S2(t1)+N2(t1)+K1(t1)+M4(t1)`

My final output is a matrix of a single vector height.  I want this to create an inundation duration curve.

Comment: Just a comment on the function I specified `hh3`. This may or may not do what you think its doing, and I suggest you check a small manual case. In particular, you need to check that when you pass `hh3` a vector/matrix that the data.table and function approach is doing what *you want it to do* for your purpose. Notice I only demonstrated it for a scalar `t`. What would be helpful (to others) is if you display an example of the output you are expecting..and what exactly you are doing with the formula. i.e. are you summing over Constituents or Names or ... neither? thanks

Comment: I did a check and it is what I need.  It is much simpler than the for loop and easier to understand for a beginner as well.

Comment: In your real data do you have multiple constituents? Or multiple Names..or both? I am trying to work out if the quantity you are calculating (height) is reported PER Name (M2,K1, etc) or Per Constituent (1, 2, etc) or neither: there is only one value of height at the end of your calcs? In your toy data both the constituent column and Name column both contained unique items. I may have misunderstood and constituent may simply be "row number" and not part of the data, etc etc.

Comment: Exactly, multiple constituents with names those are row numbers and then there are constituent names.  I believe they are part of a regression analysis, so each constituent plays a part in the wave height.  M2 for example is the Principal lunar semidiurnal constituent I need to sum all of the constituents at a particular time to calculate the height of the wave at that particular time.I have just started to learn about these for a work project, but you can find more on the NOAA website if you are interested  [link](http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/stations.html?type=Harmonic+Constituents)

Comment: OK. This is not the recommended way to do this, but would something like this work: `as.data.table(hh3(1:100))[,{sum(V1)},by=Name][,{sum(V1)}]` ? where `hh3` is `hh3<-function(t) wave_table[,{Amplitude*cos(Speed*t-Phase)}, by=Name]`

Comment: Your suggestion only returns one value.  I need multiple values summed by time. h(1)=M2(1)+S2(1)+N2(1)... ,h(2)=M2(2)+S2(2)+N2(2)... To do this I used the script below.                            `Time<-matrix(seq(0,8760,.25))  ##Create a time series
n<-hh3(Time) ##Apply height function to all constituents by time series
b<- matrix(c(rep(Time, nrow(wave_table)))) ##Create a vector of the time sequence to bind with height to separate constituents by time
height<-data.frame(colSums(dcast(data.frame(cbind(b,n)),Constituent~V1,value.var="V1.1")[,-1]))  ##Sum the constituents by time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is not an answer - but I would suggest a different approach. I will use the package `data.table` in R.

```
library(data.table)

#use own location of your data
wave_table=fread(input="F:\\wave.csv");

wave_table
#           Constituent Name Amplitude Phase Speed
#    1:           1   M2     3.264  29.0 28.98
#    2:           2   S2     0.781  51.9 30.00
#    3:           3   N2     0.630  12.3 28.43
#    4:           4   K1     1.263 136.8 15.04
#    5:           5   M4     0.043 286.0 57.96

#create a function which does your calculation on the named columns of your data, 
#taking time 't' as a parameter

hh<-function(t){ wave_table[,{Amplitude*cos(Speed*t-Phase)}] }
hh2<-function(t) wave_table[,{Amplitude*cos(Speed*t-Phase)}, by=Name]
hh3<-function(t) wave_table[,{Amplitude*cos(Speed*t-Phase)}, by=Constituent]
hh4<-function(t) wave_table[,{sum(Amplitude*cos(Speed*t-Phase))}, by=Constituent]

#Now the function `hh` can be used like this, giving you a bit 
#more flexibility with what you want to do, perhaps?

hh(1)
#3.26334722 -0.77775795 -0.57472163 -0.91362687 -0.01165717
```

or

```
hh2(1)
#   Name          V1
#1:   M2  3.26334722
#2:   S2 -0.77775795
#3:   N2 -0.57472163
#4:   K1 -0.91362687
#5:   M4 -0.01165717
```

or

```
hh4(1) #after adding an extra row to your data: "Constituent=1, Name=M3, 
#Amp=1.263,Phase=51.9, Speed=15.04
#   Constituent          V1
#1:           1  4.10718774
#2:           2 -0.77775795
#3:           3 -0.57472163
#4:           4 -0.91362687
#5:           5 -0.01165717
```

In general, loops in R for this type of problem should be avoided, as they are slow/there are much better tools available. Loops are typically "last resort".

If the function `hh` to `hh4` do not do exactly what you want, there are other variations that could be used. Check out http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf

Comment: I used Rusan's approach and finished what I was doing with what I added in my question above.  This works, but if there is a better approach please comment.